# Java and stacks: correct implementation?

Tags: java, stack

I created this very simple stack concept's implementation.
Could you tell me if it is correct and clean? Do you see any bad coding habits?

```
public class MyStack
{
    private static final int MAXELEMENTS = 10;
    private int[] elements;
    private int numElements;

    public MyStack()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        elements = new int[MAXELEMENTS];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (numElements == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull()
    {
        return (numElements == MAXELEMENTS);
    }

    public void push(int e)
    {
        if (!isFull())
            elements[numElements++] = e;
    }

    public int top()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            return elements[numElements - 1];
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        if (!isEmpty())
            numElements--;
    }
}
```

You can use it with the following code:

```
class MyStackTestDrive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyStack s1 = new MyStack();
        MyStack s2 = new MyStack();
        s1.push(2);
        s2.push(4);
        System.out.println(s1.top());
        System.out.println(s2.top());
    }
}
```

Comment: Will you ever want to put anything other than an `int` into the `Stack`? In that case, you should take a look at generics. In [one of my previous reviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/14404/9390), you can see how a solid `Stack` implementation might look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some small notes:

1. According to the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-142311.html#430),

   > if statements always use braces {}.

   Omitting them is error-prone.
2. `top`, `push` and `pop` methods handle invalid client calls too generously. You shouldn't do that. Crash early. Does it make sense to pop from an empty stack? It is rather a bug in the client code. Instead of returning `-1` or swallowing the client error throw an `IllegalStateException` or an `EmptyStackException`. See: *The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*. You could use [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) too:

   ```
   public void push(final int e) {
       if (isFull()) {
           throw new IllegalStateException();
       }
       elements[numElements++] = e;
   }

   public int top() {
       if (isEmpty()) {
           throw new EmptyStackException();
       }
       return elements[numElements - 1];
   }

   public void pop() {
       if (isEmpty()) {
           throw new EmptyStackException();
       }
       numElements--;
   }
   ```
3. I'd make the maximal number of elements configurable via the constructor:

   ```
   private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS = 10;

   private final int maxElements;
   private final int[] elements;
   private int numElements;

   public MyStack() {
       this(DEFAULT_MAX_ELEMENTS);
   }

   public MyStack(final int maxElements) {
       if (maxElements < 1) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxElements cannot be less than 1, was: " + maxElements);
       }
       this.maxElements = maxElements;
       elements = new int[maxElements];
   }
   ```
4. The default value of `int` fields are `0`, therefore `numElements = 0;` is unnecessary in the constructor.

Comment: good points; although the error message for passing too few `maxElements` into the constructor is wrong, should be *`"maxElements cannot be less than 0, was: "`* in accordance with the condition in the if-clause.

Comment: @codesparkle: Thank you, you're right. I've fixed it.

Comment: “Omitting them is error-prone.” – no, it’s simply not.

Comment: Point 1 can be contentious. It largely depends on the code standards you want to enforce (or is enforced at your workplace). If you look through the Java standard libraries you will find many instances of brackets not being used for if blocks. My personal preference is brackets for multiline conditionals, no brackets for single line conditionals. I break lines at 80.

Comment: Don't use IllegalStateException. Java provides the more specific EmptyStackException and StackOverflowError.

Comment: @Eva: `EmptyStackException` is a great insight, thank you! I've updated the answer. `StackOverflowError` is a subclass of `VirtualMachineError` which does not seem appropriate here.

Comment: Good point. I think creating a StackOverflowException subclass of IllegalStateException is [justified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/creating.html).

Answer (score 3):

Why split `top` and `pop`?

`pop` could easily return an int and adjust the number of elements.

In cases were the consumer wanted to `pop` without the int, they would just not assign the return of `pop` to a variable. And I can't think of a valid case for using `top` without using `pop`.

Comment: another good reason for `pop` to return the popped element  is consistency: [`java.util.Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) and every other implementation I can think of works this way. However, a `peek` method should remain to check the top element without removing it (there are lots of valid use cases for examining the next item without removing it). **Edit: No. It does *not* print 4 twice because two separate stacks are involved. Run the code, please.**

Comment: That's true, but it's a bit of a rabbit hole to go down. Because once you start asking if your custom stack class should use the Java stack API, I think your next question should be, do I even need a custom stack in the first place? And maybe you do for a primitive type, but then again someone has probably already done it for you. See http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/stack/TIntStack.html.

Comment: @codesparkle, You are correct, I misread the test code.